# How to add data- attributes to ExtJs rendered html?

Tags: html, dom, extjs, attributes

Using ExtJs 4.1.

I'm creating a panel (for example) and I would like that the generated html includes one or more "data-" attributes (for example: `data-intro="some text" data-step="1"`)

How can this be done?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

After the component has rendered, you could apply the attributes to the top level element representing the component

Example:

```
var panel = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel',{
    title: 'Test',
    width: 500,
    height: 200,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    listeners: {
        afterrender: function(cmp) {
            cmp.getEl().set({
                "data-intro": 'some text',
                "data-step": 1
            });
        }
    }
});

panel.show();
```

Comment: I am new to extjs, Can't we just do something like this? `....renderTo: Ext.getBody(),data-intro: 'some text', data-step: 1.....`

Comment: @Mr_Green no, that would only apply to the javascript object, not the DOM

Answer (score 16):

You can use the [`autoEl` config option](http://docs-origin.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext.panel.Panel-cfg-autoEl) to achieve this.

```
{
    xtype: 'panel',
    title: 'My Panel',
    autoEl: {
        tag: 'div',
        'data-step': '1'
    }
}
```

Comment: This works for me most of the times. Unfortunately Sencha Architect does not allow me to write this value for buttons where I have to use @James' afterrender workaround.

Comment: For Sencha Architect, just types 'autoEl' and clicks 'Add'.For Sencha Architect, just types 'autoEl' and clicks 'Add'.

Note that for Fieldset component, the default value for autoEl is 'fieldset'. If you want to add data-attribute, you must also specify 'fieldset', otherwise the rendering is distorted. Correct way is to do 

autoEl: {
    tag: 'fieldset',
    'data-cy': 'my data'
}

Answer (score 0):

```
{
    xtype: 'button',
    text: 'Button',
    ariaAttributes: {
        'aria-test-id': 'foobar',
        'data-test-id': 'foobar' // looks like any attribute can be inserted this way
    }
}
```