# add custom Html attribute in extjs 3.3

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs3

For example, a simple ExtJS TextField generates HTML like below,

```
<INPUT type=text name="txtNAME1" id="txtNAME1">
```

To this I want to add my own attribute (DisplayName) as below,

```
<INPUT type=text name="txtNAME1" id="txtNAME1" displayName="dspNAME1">
```

Comment: have a look at this question: [How to add data- attributes to ExtJs rendered html?][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15959867/how-to-add-data-attributes-to-extjs-rendered-html

Answer (score 0):

The [`autoCreate`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.form.Field-cfg-autoCreate) option lets you customize the generated element.